# I want to store on an array all orders from the customer

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, customer, magento-community

How can I get all customers orders and store it on an array ?

I've got this query, is it possible to get all the products ?

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addFieldToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
->load();
```

I really need help please!

Comment: for what reason do you need this? maybe knowing the aim would help find a solution.

Comment: I need to fill an array with all the products ordered by a customer within a certain date.

Comment: What information do you need about the product?

Comment: The name and the quantity of each product

Answer (score 1):

```
$orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addFieldToSelect(array('name', 'qty_ordered'))
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
->toArray();
```

what you then want is `$orderItems['items']`

Comment: When I added that and "echo $orders['items']" it returned this "array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-05-20 14:47:58" } } "

Comment: interessing, maybe try `addFieldToSelect('name')->addFieldToSelect('qty_ordered')`

Comment: I had a mistake with my code, now with your first answer and second one I get 
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 274534525038

Comment: than take this great debugging post by sonassi and debug: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217

Comment: I already tried to debug but no success. What I've found was if I remove "->toArray()" the error doesn't appear.

Comment: did you read the post?

Comment: Yes and I do all the steps and then I don't know what to do. I'm used to eclipse debug mode, and don't know how this one works

Comment: if you turned on the developer mode in magento you should get a real error message not the printing is disabled nonsense. And the error is in the `var/report/<errornumber>` file

Comment: I've done those 2 steps "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" and "if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || true) {
  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}" and enabled debug profiler in magento admin and it still gives me that error

Comment: Have a look into /var/reports/274534525038

Comment: This is what I get http://pastebin.com/c3EQ6aPh

Comment: ah of course. The table sales_flat_order_item has no column customer_id. You need to join into `sales_flat_order` before. Checkout `\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::join` and use the method on the collection.

Comment: And how can I do that ?

Comment: `$orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->join(array('order' => 'sales/order'), 'main_table.order_id = order.entity_id', 'order.entity_id')
    ->addFieldToSelect(array('name', 'qty_ordered'))
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
    ->toArray();` should add the join correctly